# Не работает e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Мне необходимо отправить форму без перенаправления из js в php. Конкретно в форме у меня находится input с типом file. Я пытаюсь реализовать эту отправку сразу после загрузки файла в input, никакие кнопки сразу говорю мне не нужны, нужно сделать отправку именно по изменению данных в input.

Вот форма с ипутом:

```
<form id={"thisform"} action={'http://10.10.10.10/test/filedownload.php'}>
<input id={"downloadinput"} name={"fileinchat"} type={"file"} className={"downloadfilechat"}/>
</form>
```

И вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#downloadinput").change(function(){
            if(document.getElementById('downloadinput').value === ""){

            }else{
                document.getElementById('thisform').submit();
                document.getElementById('thisform').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('');
                })
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Если я правильно помню, .submit() не тригеррит событие submit. Используйте для ваших целей ajax запрос.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как передать форму по ajax, тоже никак не получается, php документ не видит этот элемент после передачи

Comment: или как передать только input file без формы просто, тоже всячески пробовал

Answer (score 0):

Делая такую команду

```
document.getElementById('thisform').submit()
```

Ты сам отправляешь форму. Только после этого вешаешь слушателя на событие `submit`. Но если его навесить раньше, как писали выше, событие не сработает на твою команду. Форма отправится и все.

Вот пример отправки файла на сервер... Только нужно правильно определить свое поле с выбором файла.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
const data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])
fetch('тут_нужный_УРЛ', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

Comment: Теперь проблема с тем что php документ не видит отправленный ему файл

Comment: @Websocket, это уже вопрос в ПХПистам... :)

Answer (score -1):

Вот как получилось решить:

Форма:

```
<form id={"thisform"} action={'http://10.10.10.10/test/filedownload.php'}>
<inputid{"downloadinput"}name{"fileinchat"}type{"file"}className{"downloadfilechat"}>
</form>
```

Код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#downloadinput").change(function(){
            if(document.getElementById('downloadinput').value === ""){

            }else{
                $('#thisform').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    })
                })
                $('#thisform').submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

То есть нужно было добавить contentType: false просто и submit() нужно ниже вызывать.